# jQuery hover with multiple items

Tags: jquery

So I've got four circles next to each other, and when you move the mouse from one to the other, this code activates. But I only want it to activate when you move off/on any of the circles, not when you move from one .circle to another. Thanks folks!

```
 $('.circle').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).parent().animate({marginLeft: '-=25px'}, 1000);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).parent().stop(true, true).animate({marginLeft: '+=25px'}, 1000);
    }
 );
```

Comment: Register the event with the parent of all four circles and not the circles themselves?

Comment: but they are actually circles and I don't want it activating when you are outside the circles, but inside the parent.

Comment: Then use a boolean, true when already toggled and false when not. It determines when you animate and when you don't.

Comment: Could you refer me to somewhere that explains how to do that. It sounds like it would work, but I don' know how to implement it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this fiddle... http://jsfiddle.net/WxNdN/3/

e.relatedTarget should give you the element that you have entered or left.  Check its class to see if it is a circle before firing your animation.

```
$('.circle').hover(
    function (e) {

        if(!$(e.relatedTarget).hasClass('circle'))
        {
            console.log('entering');
        }
    },
    function (e) {

        if(!$(e.relatedTarget).hasClass('circle'))
        {
            console.log('leaving');
        }
    }
 );​
```

Comment: This is great, except there is space between my circles, so I think I need some delay() or something, to wait to check if the user will move over the next circle within a quarter second or something.

Comment: Do you have a public example of your circles?  I may be able to whip something nifty together tomorrow.

Comment: [Here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/maLQW/) So, yeah, it works pretty nice, but I don't like the latent left/right movement when you move from one circle to the next.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the html, I'm guessing you'd need all of the circle class elements to be wrapped within a container, and then put the hover event on the container.  So something like

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
    <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

and then

```
$('#container').hover(functions...)
```

You'd then probably have to change `$(this).parent()` but it's hard to tell without seeing your current HTML structure.